# Propel error - not writing mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, propel

I'm working with symfony and propel (symfony version 2.1.4 and propel version 1.6).
I'm following the tutorial and the save() function gives this error:

> No connection information in your runtime configuration file for datasource [users_database]

The code causing the error:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->setName('A Foo Bar');
$product->setPrice(19.99);
$product->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor');
$product->save();
```

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_driver:   mysql
    database_host:     localhost
    database_name:     users_database
    database_user:     root
    database_password: ~
    database_charset:  UTF8
```

When I check the mysql, the database is the but empty.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a try/catch around the offending code, to capture any possible exceptions?

I would try to save by manually providing the connection:

```
$product->save(\Propel::getConnection('yourconnectionname'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this on top of your script to get the error message

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```